# Where is my CreateUnlisted button?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

I just installed a dev version of the CME ( 2013 SP1).  On the Add User page there is no CreateUnlisted button.  How do I get that button?

Comment: Sounds like you're searching for an extension that someone deployed in another server...

Comment: ahhh.  Thanks.  I like that  button.  I'll find the extension.

Comment: Sounds like a nice extension that isn't listed on any blog or code site.  Maybe if you find it to post it somewhere?